# Cómo desplegar el valor IEEE-754 en hexadecimal de una variable de punto flotante?

Tags: c

Tenemos la siguiente variable:

`float pi= 3.1416;`

La cual su [representación](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) (aproximada) en IEEE-754 es:

```
0x40490ff9
```

Sabemos que si ejecutamos el siguiente código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float pi = 3.1416;

    printf("%f", pi);

    return 0;
}
```

Obtendremos como salida lo siguiente:

```
3.141600
```

Qué puedo hacer en C de forma que obtenga el número **0x40490ff9**

Answer (score 1):

La estrategia será la de engañar al compilador para que imprima el valor como un entero. Pero si intentamos lo siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    float pi = (float)3.1416;
    printf("%f\n", pi);

    printf("%x\n", (int)pi);

}
```

El cast truncará los decimales

> 3.1416
>   3

Lo mismo ocurrirá si hacemos lo siguiente:

```
printf("%x", pi);
```

El `%x`hará un cast a `int` antes de formatear la salida a hex.

Entonces, que otra alternativa tenemos? Podemos intentar con apuntadores:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    float pi = (float)3.1416;
    float* f_ptr = &pi;

    printf("%f\n", pi);
    printf("%f\n", *f_ptr);
    printf("%x\n", *((int *)f_ptr));
}﻿
```

> 3.141600
>   3.141600
>   40490ff9

La tercer salida es la que esperábamos. La segunda salida es para demostrar que si dereferenciamos el apuntador nos dará el valor de `pi`. Pero en la tercer línea:

```
printf("%x\n", *((int*)f_ptr));
```

Aquí tenemos que el segundo argumento de `printf` es un apuntador a `float` casteado a `int *`. Aquí le decimos al compilador: "Ok, yo sé que te estoy enviando un float, pero pretendamos que se trata de un apuntador a int", y entonces, una vez dereferenciado (el * mas a la izquierda, dándonos un entero), y convertiendo la salida a hexadecimal, obtenemos la salida esperada.